# "Соорудить" - этимология

Tags: этимология

Задумался над значением слова *соорудить* или *сооружение*. В поиске на первых страницах, к своему удивлению, не обнаружил. Возникают ассоциации с англ. rude. 
Может кто просветить?

Comment: Этимология rude неизвестна.

Comment: @Anixx точнее, неизвестна этимология латинского корня, а само слово rude прослеживается до этого самого корня. Автору поста: в любом случае, соорудить никакго отношения к rude не имеет.

Answer (score 3):

Ассоциации должны быть со словом "орудие", которое

> Происходит от праслав. *orǫdьje, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   церк.-слав. ору́да «работа, труд», др.-русск. орудиıе «дело; судебное
>   дело; работа; орудие, оружие» (Смол. грам. 1229 г.; ср.: тяжу урядити
>   — там же), орудовати «действовать», укр. ору́да, ст.-слав. орѫдиѥ
>   (др.-греч. πρᾶγμα, ἀπόκρισις), болг. оръ́дие «орудие, орган»,
>   словенск. оrо̑d, orȏdje — то же, чешск. orudí «орудие», польск.
>   orędzie «извещение, поручение», orędować «ходатайствовать, выполнять
>   (поручение)». Праслав. *orǫdьje связано чередованием с *rędъ (ряд,
>   снаряд). Далее сближают с греч. ἀραρίσκω «устраиваю, сплачиваю,
>   смыкаю», ἀρθμός «связь», ἄρθρον «член», лат. arma «оружие».

Источник: [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5)

[Словарь Фасмера](http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Orudie-9233.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Old Russian *орудие* meant "job, business" and was synonymous to the modern word *дело*.

So the ancestor of the word *соорудить* meant the same as the modern *сделать*. Likewise, the ancestor of the modern *сооружение* meant the same as the modern *изделие*.

The corpus mentions the Church Slavonic word *соорудитель* which had been used to translate Greek *κατασκευαστής* ("constructor, designer").